# MariaDB: How to compare JSON values?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, json

How to compare JSON values in MariaDB?

**MariaDB 10.2 and 10.3 - Fails:**

```
SELECT CAST('{"q":2}' AS JSON);
```

Returns:

```
SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'JSON)' at line 1
```

**MySQL 5.7.19 - Works:**

```
SELECT CAST('{"num": 1.1, "date": "2015-11-01"}' AS JSON) = CAST('{"date": "2015-11-01", "num": 1.1}' AS JSON);
```

Returns: `1`

> Source: http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2015/11/mysql-few-observations-on-json-type.html

**Other similar questions**

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46734547/compare-json-values-in-mariadb) but my JSON is more complex.

Comment: If you sort keys, recursively, on the client side, before your store, you can compare JSON_COMPACT(a) to JSON_COMPACT(b) . If you also remove spaces, before you send to server, you can just compare strings.

Comment: I know. That was my fallback idea too. :) I tried JSON_COMPACT - it works ok.

Comment: cf https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-11439

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is not, as of 10.3.7, a native JSON type on mariadb server**. JSON is only an alias for LONGBLOB for compatibility reasons with MySQL: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json-data-type/

While there is a library of function to work with JSON https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json-functions/ (select and transform it); there isn't really a native type, so all input and output of those functions is really of type string. While you could technically implement a recursive json parser with a stored procedure, **I would recommend to just read it and compare it with client libraries or other client utilities** (for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25851183/how-to-compare-two-json-objects-with-the-same-elements-in-a-different-order-equa ).

Despite the claims by MariaDB that it is a drop-in replacement of MySQL, because MariaDB is no longer a 100% compatible fork, functionalities that are available on one software are no longer available on the other and viceversa.

Comment: Too bad for MariaDB. It looks like it must be done on client side. At least for now (v10.3).

Comment: @hrvoj3e If you are happy with the answer (even if that makes you unhappy), you can accept it as valid, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I work for MariaDB

As of 10.7 you will be able to use the new functions JSON_EQUALS and JSON_NORMALIZE. See related tickets/implementation at:

- https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-23143 (Add JSON_EQUALS function to check JSON equality)
- https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-16375 (Add JSON_NORMALIZE function to normalize JSON values)
- https://github.com/MariaDB/server/pull/1863 (Implementation)

```
MariaDB-10.7>SELECT JSON_NORMALIZE('{"A": 1, "C": 3, "B": 2}');
+--------------------------------------------+
| JSON_NORMALIZE('{"A": 1, "C": 3, "B": 2}') |
+--------------------------------------------+
| {"A":1.0E0,"B":2.0E0,"C":3.0E0}            |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

```
MariaDB-10.7>SELECT JSON_EQUALS('{"A": 1, "C": 3, "B": 2}','{"A":1.0E0,"B":2.0E0,"C":3.0E0}');
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| JSON_EQUALS('{"A": 1, "C": 3, "B": 2}','{"A":1.0E0,"B":2.0E0,"C":3.0E0}') |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                         1 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

From MariaDB 10.2.3 you can use [JSON_CONTAINS](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_contains/).

```
SELECT JSON_CONTAINS(
    '{"num": 1.1, "date": "2015-11-01"}'
    , '{"date": "2015-11-01", "num": 1.1}');
```

Returns: `1`

However, this will also return `1`:

```
SELECT JSON_CONTAINS(
    '{"num": 1.1, "date": "2015-11-01", "Extra":"My extrafield"}'
    , '{"date": "2015-11-01", "num": 1.1}');
```

So to see if the contains the same data, you can use:

```
SET @json1 := '{ "num": 1.1, "date": "2015-11-01"}';
SET @json2 := '{"date": "2015-11-01", "num": 1.1}';

SELECT JSON_CONTAINS(@json1, @json2) AND JSON_CONTAINS(@json2, @json1);
```

Returns: `1`

Be aware that lists doesn't have to be equal, just contain the same elements.

```
SET @json1 := '{ "num": 1.1, "date": "2015-11-01", "List":[1,2,2,2,2] }';
SET @json2 := '{"List":[2,1], "date": "2015-11-01", "num": 1.1}';

SELECT JSON_CONTAINS(@json1, @json2) AND JSON_CONTAINS(@json2, @json1);
```

Returns:  `1`